# Screen colors are inverted on Ubuntu 22.04 when using the "Try Ubuntu" feature

Tags: nvidia, system-installation

I decided to switch to Ubuntu 22.04 (first time Linux) and wanted to install it from my USB flash drive (32GB). I've correctly set it in the bios to boot from.
Then I was greeted with a normal "Try Ubuntu" or "Install Ubuntu" Window. At this point, the screen colors were normal.

I tried to test my compatibility first like recommended. When the desktop appeared, the colors were inverted, as is visible in this picture: https://postimg.cc/cg38NYBY. I have two screens and both are suffering from this color inversion problem. Both do not have HDRI, and the problem remains if I set Ubuntu to display on only one screen.

If my specs are relevant: 
GPU: 3070, CPU: 9600kf, MOBO: Gigabyte Z390 Gaming X, 32 GB Ram

Comment: Here is the picture: https://postimg.cc/cg38NYBY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1969959

The default open-source driver in Ubuntu is somehow getting confused about how your screen is supposed to display, thus why your screen looks so bad when you boot into the live environment. There are two solutions to the problem.

The first one is to set the color profile properly on your display. Click on the System Menu in the upper-right hand corner of the screen (the place where the speaker and other icons are), and then click "Settings". From there, in the menu on the left side of the settings window, find "Color".

Select your screen, then click "Add Profile", and find "Colorspace: sRGB". Then click "Add". The screen should immediately look normal. This will allow you to finish testing out Ubuntu and make sure that everything else works.

The second solution is to fully install Ubuntu, making sure to enable proprietary drivers during the installation.

If you use the first solution, and then discover that Ubuntu works acceptably on your hardware, you can fully install it with the proprietary drivers and your screen should still look normal once the installation is done. Using the proprietary drivers will also help you get the most performance out of your graphics card.